# java script error with jquery tool tip on IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer-10

I have the following code that runs well on all the browsers except on IE 10.

I am running my code in Visual Studio, .NET framework 4.0. I just recently updated to IE 10.

Java Script Code

```
$(function () {
    var du = 1000;
    var tooltip;
    $(document).tooltip({
        show:{effect:'slideDown'},
        hide:{effect:'explode',pieces:20,duration:du,delay:du/100},
        track: true,

            items: "h5",
            content: function () {
                tooltip = $(this).siblings('.tooltip');
                return tooltip.html();
        }
    });
    });
```

aspx Code :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rpt_ItemCommand"
                                            OnItemDataBound="rpt_OnItemDataBound">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Panel ID="Pnl" runat="server">
                                                        <div class="tooltip" style="display: none">
                                                            <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
                                                                <%# Eval("Name") %><br />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <table align="center">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <div style="font-weight: normal">
                                                                            Calls
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <div style="font-weight: normal">
                                                                            Success
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <div style="font-weight: normal">
                                                                            Error
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: normal">
                                                                            <%# Eval("TotalCalls")%>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: normal">
                                                                            <%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("TotalCalls")) - Convert.ToInt32(Eval("ErrorCalls"))%>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: normal">
                                                                            <%# Eval("ErrorCalls")%><br />
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                            <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: normal">
                                                                Success Rate =
                                                                <%# ((decimal)Eval("PassPercentage") == -1) ? "0.0 %" : Eval("PassPercentage") + "%"%>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                </asp:Panel>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:Repeater>
```

I get the following error :

```
JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'tooltip'
```

Is there a way I can resolve the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing the same issue .Changing the jquery reference to the latest version 1.10.3 resolved the problem for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```